# Django Stale Model Objects and Forms ChoiceField vs ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

This is just a curiosity that bugs me. I created a Form class to handle document selection from a database. Naturally, one must get the list of documents from the database to populate the available choices. I get "stale" behavior from building the choices manually and using a ChoiceField. But I get the accurate result when utilizing the ModelChoiceField option "queryset".

By "stale" I mean if I upload a new document and render the page, the list shows only the old set of documents (sometimes persisting even after refresh of the page, which according to the view logic should regenerate the form--proof of this is the fact that the second method works as expected no matter the use case).
Example as follows:

Stale version:

```
class GetDocumentForm(forms.Form):
    document_query   = Document.objects.all().order_by('docfile')
    document_choices = []

    for document in document_query:
        document_choices.append((document.id, document.docfile.name))

    document         = forms.ChoiceField(label='', choices=document_choices)
```

Accurate version:

```
class GetDocumentForm(forms.Form):
    document         = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Document.objects.all())
```

What gives? What's the difference? Why do they behave differently?

Comment: the stale version class body should be inside `__init__` method!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the stale version class body should be inside `__init__` method! – mariodev

Thank you mariodev.

Following this lead, I was able to generate code that functioned properly. My first attempt still failed to work properly:

```
class GetDocumentForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.base_fields['document'].choices = self.document_choices[:]
```

This would allow me to create a form, but when I attempted to render:

```
In [1]: from WebSite.forms import *

In [2]: doc_form = GetDocumentForm()

In [3]: print doc_form.as_p()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

AttributeError: 'GetDocumentForm' object has no attribute '_errors'
```

The solution is here: [StackOverflow -- Django: Overloading **init** for Custom Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/871037/1870013). You need the super class.

Final, working code:

```
class GetDocumentForm(forms.Form):
    document          = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GetDocumentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for doc in Document.objects.all().order_by('docfile'):
            self.fields['document'].choices.append((doc.id, doc.docfile.name))
```

Clearly using `ModelChoiceField(queryset=Document.objects.all())` is much more succinct. But the point was to understand how to get it to work both ways.

Cheers.

Comment: Glad I could help. Also, since you're accessing related field `doc.docfile.name` you need to use `select_related()` in the query, to avoid multiple db hit.